# Rails 5 display current users contacts

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am trying to show only the current_user contacts via the rails `current_user` method:

```
def index
    if params[:category_id] && !params[:category_id].empty?
      category_find = Category.find(params[:category_id])
      @contacts = category_find.current_user.contacts.search(params[:term]).order(created_at: :desc).page params[:page]
    else
      @contacts = Contact.current_user.search(params[:term]).order(created_at: :desc).page params[:page]
    end
  end
```

contacts model:

```
   scope :search, -> (term) do
    where('LOWER(name) LIKE :term or LOWER(email) LIKE :term or LOWER(country) LIKE :term', term: "%#{term.downcase}%") if term.present?
  end
```

But it returns `unfined method current_user`.

what am I doing here that prevents me from showing the contacts only for the current user?

EDIT:

Here's the user contact:

```
class Contact < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :category
  has_one_attached :contact_avatar
  belongs_to :user


  validates :name, :email, presence: true
  validates_length_of :name, minimum: 3
  validates_length_of :mobile, minimum: 7, maximum: 15, allow_blank: true
  validates_length_of :phone, minimum: 7, maximum: 15, allow_blank: true


  scope :search, -> (term) do
    where('LOWER(name) LIKE :term or LOWER(email) LIKE :term or LOWER(country) LIKE :term', term: "%#{term.downcase}%") if term.present?
  end


end
```

Here's the User model.

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :contacts
  has_many :categories

  # Include default devise modules. Others available are:
  # :confirmable, :lockable, :timeoutable, :trackable and :omniauthable
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :validatable

  has_one_attached :user_avatar
end
```

Here's the category model:

```
class Category < ApplicationRecord
    has_many :contacts
    belongs_to :user
end
```

Note I am using devise gem for authentication.

Comment: Check if there's really a category with the category_id you're receiving in your database.

Comment: Yes. I am receiving it on my database.

Comment: Sorry, didn't see the other use of current_user. What's `Contact.current_user`?

Comment: I am trying to pull up all the Contacts of the current user (the one that is login)

Comment: How's it defined? In this case it does matter how's defined, you can add it to your question.

Comment: Can you add your contact model and user model. Seems like issue with association. You can find all contact of current user with `current_user.contacts`. One more thing current_user is devise object not rails.

Comment: Full error message would probably be helpful. As it is now, one cannot figure out even the class of receiver of `current_user` call which failed.

Comment: sure let me share all the details

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This will work for you.

```
  def index
    if params[:category_id].present?
        category = Category.find(params[:category_id])
        @contacts = category.current_user.contacts
    else
        @contacts = current_user.contacts
    end
    @contacts = @contacts.search(params[:term]).order(created_at: :desc).page params[:page]
  end
```

You can use safe navigator also, If you get any nil error.

Better way to get pagination object first and then filter record on the basis of incoming params like below.

```
def index
  // Here we are trying to fetch all contacts of current user, order and paginate also.
  @contacts = current_user.contacts.order(created_at: :desc).page(params[:page])
  // Here we are filtering current user all contact for particular category if category_id is present.  
  @contacts = @contacts.where(category_id: params[:category_id]) if params[:category_id].present?
  // Here we are filtering records with search term
  @contacts = @contacts.search(params[:term]) if params[:term].present?
end
```

Comment: Is there a way to refactor this?

Comment: "You can use safe navigator also, If you get any nil error.". No no no no. Huge anti-pattern. If you use the safe navigator here then the order and pagination will not be applied.

Comment: I really like the 2nd one. Superb compress. Would you mind on explaining that 2nd part per line? Sorry I am super beginner in Rails I want to understand each step. Please.

Comment: added comments in action

Answer (score 0):

You have `User#contacts` and `User#categories` associations, just use them:

```
def index
  if params[:category_id] && !params[:category_id].empty?
    category = Category.find(params[:category_id])
    @contacts = current_user.contacts.where(category: category)
  else
    @contacts = current_user.contacts
  end
  @contacts = @contacts.search(params[:term]).order(created_at: :desc)
end
```

or maybe even better (with some refactoring):

```
@contacts = current_user.contacts.search(params[:term]).order(created_at: :desc)
if params[:category_id].present?
  category = Category.find(params[:category_id])
  @contacts = @contacts.where(category: category)
end
```

Answer (score 0):

If you really wanted to make this chainable you should write it as:

```
class Contact < ApplicationRecord
  # ...

  # don't use scope for anything except oneliners
  def self.search(term)
    return self unless term.present? # prevents nil error
    where(
      'LOWER(name) LIKE :term or LOWER(email) LIKE :term or LOWER(country) LIKE :term',
      term: "%#{term.downcase}%"
    )
  end

  def self.by_category(category_id)
    category_id.present? ? where(category_id: category_id) : self
  end
end
```

The key is that your "scopes" (which are really just class methods) must always return a ActiveRecord::Relation or self which prevents nil errors.

```
def index
   @contacts = current_user.contacts
                             .search(params[:term])
                             .by_category(params[:category_id])
                             .order(created_at: :desc)
                             .page(params[:page])
end
```